# How to use conditional statement with query result?

Tags: php, mysql

It seems to not read the data within bc in my conditional statement, it goes right to the else. I'm not sure what to do

```
$mem = "SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(StartMem,INTERVAL i MONTH)) AS Months FROM oatdis CROSS JOIN counter WHERE DATE_ADD(StartMem,INTERVAL i MONTH)<=EndMem AND Name = 'John'";
$memRes = mysqli_query($conn,$mem);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($memRes as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    if($data == "January"){
        echo json_encode("Jan");
    }
    else if($data == "Febuary"){
        echo json_encode("Feb");
    }
    else if($data == "March"){
        echo json_encode("Mar");
    }
    else if($data == "April"){
        echo json_encode("April");
    }
    else if($data == "May"){
        echo json_encode("May");
    }
    else if($data == "June"){
        echo json_encode("June");
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode("Didn't receive");
    }
```

the query result is as follows:

```
| Months |
|--------|
|January |
|Febuary |
|March   |
```

Comment: As `$data` is an array, how do you want each item to display.  At the moment you are saying does an array match a particular month.

Comment: yeah that was the goal

Comment: How can that be your goal?? `if($data == "January"){` is saying "does this list of names equal January". Clearly that's nonsensical - a list cannot equal a text value. Are you wanting to see if the array _contains_ that value? And why are you json_encoding single values within the if statements? That doesn't really achieve anything.

Comment: I suppose, what you're looking is `in_array` function instead, not the `==` condition. Try replacing them with something like `if(in_array("January", $data))`.

Comment: Sorry, but yes what I meant was wanting to see if the array contains the value, I tried the in_array but didn't seem to work either, it still directly went to the else statement

Comment: Can you tell us what's the result of `var_dump($data);` before the if-else block?

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Months"]=>
    string(3) "May"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Months"]=>
    string(4) "June"
  }
}

Comment: that is the results from the var_dump

Comment: Here you go... So, the quickfix is following. You have to do a small change in for loop. Replace `$data[] = $row;` with `$data[] = $row['Months'];` and use `in_array`.